# How can I SaveAs a new workbook to original workbook directory with Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, filepath, save-as

Basically, I'd like to save some worksheets into separate new workbooks in the same system location as original notebook I am deriving from.

I recognize that the default path is to save something new is to the location of the current notebook, but perhaps since I am opening a new workbook the default reverts to the user's Document's folder, which is where they are saving right now.

I "learned" VBA over the last couple of days, so advice on other things you notice is cool too, but the saveas is what's bothering me.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim dept_array As Variant
Dim dept As Variant

' Add or remove a department name spelled exactly as it is in the filter
dept_array = Array("HR", "IT", "Marketing", "Product Marketing", "Sales", "Channels", "Presales", "Direct", "Sales Ops", "R&D", "Support", "G&A")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each ws In Workbooks("Weekly Department Transaction Report.xlsm").Worksheets
    For Each dept In dept_array
        If Application.Proper(ws.Name) = Application.Proper(dept) _
        Then
             Set wb = Workbooks.Add
             ThisWorkbook.Sheets(dept).Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
             wb.Saveas dept & "_" & Format(Now, "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsx"
             Workbooks("Weekly Department Transaction Report.xlsm").Sheets("Codes").Copy After:=Workbooks(dept & "_" & Format(Now, "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsx").Sheets(dept)
             Workbooks("Weekly Department Transaction Report.xlsm").Sheets("How").Copy Before:=Workbooks(dept & "_" & Format(Now, "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsx").Sheets(dept)
             Workbooks(dept & "_" & Format(Now, "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsx").Save
        End If
    Next dept
Next ws

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Please let me know if I am not following the correct stackoverflow format. 
Longtime user first time asker :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit this line in your code:

```
wb.SaveAs FileName:= ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & dept & "_" & Format(Now, "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsx"
```

Comment: minty;fresh;beautiful. Thank you